# Fat Models, working out variables based on other date

Tags: django, forms, django-models

I am still fairly new to Django but I am trying to stick to the fat model, thin controller aspects of Django.

I have a price input that could change so this has been assigned to a form:

```
class AdminData(models.Model):
year1 = models.IntegerField()
year3 = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to work out the day_rate for these services based on different factors such as weeks in a year and hours per day which are fixed outside my model

```
    weeksinyear = 52
```

How can I get a day_rate fixed variable based on the user input for a 1 year and 3 year options, my initial thoughts were to create a variable like below, which does not work.

```
week_rate_year1 = year1 / weeksinyear
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, am I suppose to do this via models or should this code run in the template or view? As it is a static value based on the user inputted value I am not sure.

Thanks for helping a noob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple Python [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) would do...

```
class AdminData(models.Model):
    year1 = models.IntegerField()
    year3 = models.IntegerField()

    @property
    def week_rate_year1(self):
        return self.year1 / weeksinyear
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it was so obvious!

Comment: How would I test the value is pulling through correctly?

Comment: As in an unit test? `x = AdminData(year1=520); assert x.week_rate_year1 == 10` should do, right?

Comment: I get an AssertionError? What is this?

Comment: Well, what do you mean with "test the value is pulling through correctly"?

Comment: the year1 has a number put into it that is in the database but I want to test that the value displayed for the rate is correct. The year1 and year3 can change. i tried putting it into a template to test and didnt get anything.

Comment: Tried putting what into a template? What about the view? Maybe you should ask another question with all of your current code and what's wrong with it.